# How can I allow a user to change his password if they are signed out?

Tags: java, android, firebase-authentication

I'm using Firebase Authentication.
I have a phone verification.
Suppose some user forgot his/her password while he/she is signed out.

After phone verification, I want to allow him/her to change his/her password. (He/she is not signed in).
I can't use `getCurrentUser()` because he is not signed in.
User's account is created with email(email sign in method). but verification is made with phone number.
So, how can I do this??

Comment: You get the email related to the phone verification and reset its password ?

Comment: Yes.
That's what I want.

Answer (score 1):

You can change a user's password with [updatePassword()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseUser#updatePassword(java.lang.String)).  That is a method of the class [FirebaseUser](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseUser).  You can only get one of these objects when the user is signed in.  So, it's not possible to have a user change their own password unless they are signed in.

The only alternative to this is to build a "back door" that allows a user to fill out some form and submit it to your backend, so that you can use the [Firebase Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin) to [update the user account](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#update_a_user) directly, bypassing the normal security concerns.  The Admin SDK only runs on backends, and not in client apps.

Comment: Thank you sir.
This helped me a lot

Comment: Sir, I looked up the documentations you provided!
But I couldn't understand properly. 
It seems little bit complicated :(  
@Doug Stevenson